# Render partial from modal box using "onclick"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is possible to render partial using onclick in modal box ?

```
   <%= submit_tag "#{t('send')} #{t('message')}", :class => "modal-box-cancel_button submit-button",:onclick=> ... (code) %>
```

Render to _conversation

Comment: You can let the onclick do a request to a controller#action and from there render a partial.

Comment: can you give me example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the onclick send a request to the server and from there render the partial:
Do not use onclick attribute but give it an id and let JS handle it.

```rb
<%= submit_tag "#{t('send')} #{t('message')}", class: 'modal-box-cancel_button submit-button', id: 'some_logic_id' %>
```

Now you need some JavaScript to listen if the button is being clicked and let it send a request to the server:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (event.target.id === "some_fancy_id") {
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "/some_url",
      type: "post",
      data: "attribute=value"
    });
  }
};
```

So with the above code you add an event listener to the document. If you click anywhere on the document it will check if the thing you clicked on has the id: some_fancy_id. If it has that id, it will send a post request to `/some_url` (you need to add this to your routes), the data part is only needed if you want to send some data to the server. Let's say you would want to send a user_id you could fill the data part with: `user_id=1`.

Now you need to add a route to handle this request:

```rb
post 'some_fancy_url', to: 'controller#action'
# for example: requests_controller#display_partial
```

Now you need to create a view file for that `controller#action`.

```rb
# /views/requests/display_partial.js.erb

# class based
$('.some_class').html("<%= j (render partial: 'path_to_partial_name') %>")

# id based
$('#some_id').html("<%= j (render partial: 'path_to_partial_name') %>")
```

With the above code you select the class or id and inside that you render the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the partial inside the modal and associate the modal with the button using data-target attribute.

example with bootstrap:

```
<%= button_tag "#{t('send')} #{t('message')}", :class => "modal-box-cancel_button submit-button", data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#exampleModal' } %>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render partial 'partial_path' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```